# For look to create smaller data frames

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to create a data frame base in a search of a bigger data frame

Big Data frame:

```
 4 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

 5 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

      .

      .



 6 LW1002            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

 7 LW1002            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

 8 LW1002            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

 9 LW1003            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test
```

I want data frame like below:

```
 4 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

 5 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

 6 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test


 7 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

 8 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test

 9 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test


for(i in ModulesWithMarks)
{


  i <- ModuleMarks[ModuleMarks$Module==i,]

}
```

I'm trying above, does anyone have any ideas on this ?
is the for loop wrong or is there a better way?

subset by the 2nd column, The for loop works, but, I does not create data frame. So whats happening is that I am getting the last rows with the same column in a table called `i`. .....

So it is processing it in the for loop but its not creating the tables programatically..... I'm getting `LWxxxx` (end data frame) and its called `i` but I should be getting `LW1001` Dataframe, `LW1002` Dataframe for all the unique values in the 2nd column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I undestand but if I do, you want to subset by the second column:

```
 df2 = df[df[,2]=="LW1001",]
```

To loop for each you'd say something like:

```
   for(i in unique(df[,2])){assign(i,  df[df[,2]==i,])}
```

You don't have to loop though, look into `split`

Comment: Thanks much appreciated

Comment: @pat, if this answer helped you and you'd like to close the question, could you accept the answer by clicking on the check mark? You can wait for better answers, or change to a better answer in the future as well.

Comment: Yes I want to subset by the 2nd column, The for loop works, but, I does not create data frame. So whats happening is that I am getting the last rows with the same column in a table called i.  ..... So it is processing it in the for loop but its not creating the tables programaticall..... I'm getting LWxxxx (end data frame) but I should be getting LW1001 Dataframe, LW1002 Dataframe. .. Thanks

Comment: Edited to use assign to save each subset as an object

Comment: Thank you Olivia, I spent the weekend mulling this over in my head, It works! Thanks again.